# How can I store the data I get from a Promise back into an object with the same key it came from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A bit of an ambiguous title, but I'll explain...

I am making a `fetch` call to 4 different URLs from **The Movie Database**.
Once these fetch calls retrieve the data, it will then `setState` and update my initial state. However, I don't want my page to load until all of the data is retrieved, so I am using `Promise.all` (or attempting to).

My code so far...

```
  state = {
    movies: {
      trending: {},
      topRated: {},
      nowPlaying: {},
      upcoming: {},
     },
  };




 const allMovieURLs = {
      trending: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
      topRated: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
      nowPlaying: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
      upcoming: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
    };

//initialize an empty array to Promise.all on
const promiseArr = [];

//loop through movie URLs, call fetch + json()
for (const movies in allMovieURLs) {
  //create an object that directly describes the data you get back from the url with a key
  const obj = {
    [movies]: fetch(allMovieURLs[movies]).then(res => res.json())
  };
  //push that object into an array so you can use Promise.all
  promiseArr.push(obj);
```

Now what I have here is an array (`promiseArr`) of objects that have the correct key with the correct `Promise` stored inside of them.

My next plan was going to be to call `Promise.all` on them, but I need an array of promises. After I get the actual data back from the URL calls, I wanted to store them back in the object, to the correct corresponding key?

I've been stuck at this part for a couple hours now...any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async/await` and `Object.entries()` to convert a JavaScript plain object to an array of arrays of key, value pairs

```
(async() => {
  for (const [movie, url] of Object.entries(allMovieURLs)) {
    try {
      allMovieURLs[movie] = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
                                  .catch(e => {throw e})
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call then when adding to promise array. Instead call it in promise all

```
const trending = fetch(trending);
...

Promise.all([trending, topRated, nowplaying, upcoming]).then(([trending, topRated, nowplaying, upcoming]) => {
   movies.trending = trending.json();
   ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just also store the promises themselves in another array.

```js
function fetch() {
    var time = Math.random() * 1E3;
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            res(time);
        }, time);
    });
}

const API_KEY = "";

const allMovieURLs = {
    trending: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
    topRated: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
    nowPlaying: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
    upcoming: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
};

const promiseArr = [];
const promises = [];

for (const movies in allMovieURLs) {
    const obj = { [movies]: undefined };
    promises.push(fetch(allMovieURLs[movies]).then(res => obj[movies] = res));
    promiseArr.push(obj);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log(promiseArr);
});
```

If that is not feasible, you can do something like: `Promise.all(promiseArr.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0]))`